What's the subject of かかる?
As I understand, the verb かかる (as in "take time/money") is intransitive. I have found of couple of usages of this verb to express duration that made my head spin a little. The meaning is clear, the grammar is not. So, let me consider the following sentence/phrase first

時間がかかる。

meaning "it takes time". Now, I know that the English grammar for this sentence is very different, so let's just stick to the Japanese one. Being followed by the particle が, 「時間」seems to be the subject of 「かかる」.
On the other hand, I often see sentences like:

2時間かかる。

meaning "it takes two hours" (or with other time units of course). In this case, the particle が is missing, so I'm wondering if that's just some idiomatic omission or the grammatical structure is different from the previous sentence. I would say that in both cases, what is taking time (a job, a trip etc.) is here omitted. it would typically be the topic は (not necessary explicit) of the sentence (In most cases, I guess?), still the absence of が makes me wonder if there is actually something different or it's just usage and whether it would be wrong to remove (add) が  in the first (second) sentence. I would appreciate if you answered this question making clear the subjects, even adding pieces (e.g. topic) to make it clearer.

It feels to me that ２時間 in the second sentence acts almost like an adverb. I am unsure what the omitted subject may be, if any.

Do you mean as in 「昨日は３時間勉強しました。」？

yes, in a similar sentence structure to that.

かかる has two different usages, one with time as the subject, and one with a task as the subject:

その作業を終えるのに2時間がかかる。
To finish the task, two hours are required.
その作業を終えるのに時間がかかる。
To finish the task, time is required.
その作業が2時間かかる。
The task takes two hours.

When a task is the subject, the corresponding number is expressed adverbially. In Sentence 3, "2時間" is working as an adverb, and it takes no additional particle.
Now, what about your sentence, "2時間かかる"? Since this sentence sounds natural even in a completely formal style where no particles are omitted, I think it's usually better to consider 2時間 as an adverb. However, when you're speaking informally, it's not wrong to interpret it as a sentence where が has been omitted from a sentence like Sentence 1.
On the other hand, the subject of 時間がかかる is 時間, even though this phrase is usually translated as "It takes (some) time". When you say 時間かかる (without が), it sounds fairly colloquial/informal because this 時間 (without a corresponding number) cannot be interpreted as an adverb.

No one else answered yet so I will. I really wish someone with better intuition than I would've answered this instead.
Firstly, I highly doubt that “３時間かかる” is a case of particle dropping. This seems to function as a durational adverb similar to how we can say “３時間散歩していた。”, durational adverbs in Japanese often look similar to nouns but they're not. A sentence such as “私のことを何も知らないのに。” seems to at first glance have two objects, but “何も” apart from a noun can also function as an adverb that indicates the extend of the verb, as such it's similar to “ちっとも” here. It just so happens that in this case of the durational adverb, it has the same function as another part of speech, but that's also the case in “何も知らない”, whether “何も” is analysed as a durational adverb or an object, the result is the same, we can only see it must be a durational adverb in that example sentence, because a true object marked with “〜を” already exists, and Japanese sentences cannot have two objects.
However, in the case of “するのには３時間がかかる” I believe the part marked with “〜に” is probably a so-called dative subject, and the part marked with “〜が” is probably a nominative object. Part of the argument for this is indeed that “するのには３時間かかる" without an object while retaining a subject and without it being possible to really introduce the part marked with “〜が” again while keeping the adverb which suggests that it is not a subject which should be the primary argument that can always be introduced. Though admittedly the arguments to make the case that the part marked with “〜が” is not the subject are weaker here since the usual arguments of reflexive pronouns, subject honorification and such don't apply here since the subject is inanimate by nature. However I can think of another test as an example:

昨日は時間がかかりながらも焼けていたのに 今日はちっとも進みませんでした。 -> “Despite burning while taking its time yesterday, it didn't progress one bit today.”

This “時間がかかりながら” of which ample examples can be found does suggest that “時間が” is not the grammatical subject of this phrase since clauses ending in “〜ながら” must always share the same subject as their matrix clause. In case you not know what “dative subjects” and “nominative objects” are in Japanese there is much written about it but essentially it comes down to that, like here, a clause marked with what would normally be used for the subject, as in “〜が” actually grammatically speaking has object properties. The most famous example of this construct is “私にこれがわかる” where “私に” despite being marked with “〜に” functions as the subject and “これが” despite being marked with “〜が” functions as the object.

Again, "nominative object" is only an artifact of thinking about this in English. Frankly, I think this is more confusing to people.  As an alternative parsing of 「するのには３時間がかかる」 that hews closer to how the Japanese actually works, "in the doing, three hours apply". There is no object here, nominative or otherwise, in the Japanese.

Separately, your sentence starting with "Part of the argument" is grammatically confused, and I cannot tell what you're trying to say there; you may want to edit that.

@EiríkrÚtlendi Sounds like I've missed some context between the two of you, but, why do you say this involves English? There are syntactic subjecthood and objethood tests you can perform in Japanese to show that some nominative-case (= が-marked) arguments behave like objects. Though I'm not sure if かかる would pass those, nor am I sure if the demonstration with ながら here sufficiently counts as one.

@Ody, well like I said it's flimsy because the usual tests of subject honorification and “〜たい” don't really work here since the subject is by definition inanimate, as in I don't think it'll ever be used to mean “I take 20 minutes to get ready.” as in English but simply “getting ready takes 20 minutes” but I think the “〜ながら” argument is pretty solid. We can evidently not say “私が食べながらあなたがテレビを見る” and yet “時間がかかりながら焼けていた” seems to be grammatical. I would also say that “時間がかかりたい。” is “poised” to mean “wants to take time” not “time wants to be taken” despite probably not being natural.

@Ody, but again, I wanted someone with better intuition about this than I to answer this. All these things aren't very commonly used so I'm not sure how reliable my intuition about all this is. There's a good chance my feeling of “〜たい” is entirely wrong here.

Ah, right, I was thinking they're kinda nonapplicable but I skimmed over the part in your answer where you say so yourself. My bad. As for ながら, the main thing making me reluctant is that I've just never seen it used as a test in the literature (though admittedly I'm not exactly well-read). Can you really say that two verbs can be joined by ながら iff they share a subject? This seems slightly off-mark. A counterexample would be with "possessive" いる. I got a handful of hits for this, e.g.「彼女がいながら他の女に手を出す」. 彼女 here is a subject per the honorific/anaphor definition (+ animacy agreement as a bonus).

@Ody, no these are also used as arguments that in that sense of “いる” it is an object. Subject honorification also works it, as in with “ある” we can say “おありですか？” whether it evidently honors the part marked with “〜に”, not wth “〜が” though I will say that “ある" and “いる” sort of sit in a space in between as in we cannot say “妹がいたい” to mean “I want a younger sister” and “妹がいてほしい” has to be used so it functions as a subject, sort of for that, note the use of “〜が" rather than “〜に” again. “〜ながら” is well known to require the clause to share the same subject with it's matrix clause.

You sure? Possessive ある does take NOM objects, but afaik the equivalent construction with いる is a double-subject one. See this answer. (Btw for further discussion we should probably move to the chat room, since this is getting pretty long, so ping me there if you want to keep this going.)

Dear @Zorf I have logged and read your answer, which you wrote a couple of days ago. Since Naruto's answer is easier to understand and more straight to the point, I will accept that, but I appreciate your effort in writing all this.
